# What does drag mean in the context of a bull being chained to a drag?

Tags: meaning

My question comes after reading the [William Carlos Williams' poem The Bull:](https://www.poetrynook.com/poem/bull-2)

"...chained / to a drag / the bull is godlike"

I would be very grateful for an explanation.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you look up the word [*drag*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drag) in a dictionary? Without any other context, it most likely means something similar to "chained to a plow."

Comment: I removed your tag *single-word-requests* as it doesn't seem you're asking for a word.

Answer (score 9):

According to the OED, "drag" can be short for "drag-harrow":

> A heavy kind of harrow used for breaking up ground or breaking clods; a drag-harrow.

(This sense is marked as "historical" in some other dictionaries.)

[One site](https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/concord-6-ft-drag-harrow) sells drag harrows and they look like this:

> [image]

Comment: For loose definitions of "historical" -- when I was a child, we had one for dragging behind a tractor.

Answer (score 4):

a drag  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57406?rskey=nEhG67&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> 3. Something that drags, or hangs heavily, so as to impede motion.

As in:

> the bull is impeded for safety, but allowed to graze.

[image: chained bull]

Comment: I think this is the correct answer..an image would be very helpful.

Comment: If the purpose is to keep the bull in place, then why would he be chained to something that only impedes motion, rather than to an immovable fixture?

Comment: to keep him from the cows ... they can move faster than him! lol

Comment: @michael.hor257k so he can graze and get to water probably. Camels have their legs tied together with a short length of rope so they can move a bit but not run or even walk efficiently; a heavy stone or log would have a similar effect

Comment: If the bull were tied to an immovable object, you would quickly learn the rope is breakable.